# Recorrer un Array Guardado de una Consulta en PHP

Tags: php, ciclos

Saludos a todos, mi asunto es el siguiente, tengo el guardado de una consulta

```
$datosMotivos= array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

$cod=$row['cod'];
$descripcion=$row['descripcion'];
$motivo=$row['motivo'];
$lugar=$row['lugar'];

$datosMotivos[] = array('cod'=> $cod, 'descripcion'=> $descripcion, 'motivo'=> $motivo, 'lugar'=> $lugar); 
}
```

Deseo recorrerlo en el mismo archivo PHP para otro proceso que estoy haciendo, ¿Cuál es la forma adecuada de recorrer dicho arreglo guardado? Estoy abierto a sus sugerencias y consejos, gracias por su tiempo.

**P.D:** Aclarando el tema, para mi caso particular necesito recorrer el array por fuera del while que les muestro, ya que asignar valores que estén dentro de este while ya lo sé realizar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para recorrer el Array `$datosMotivos` luego de haber almacenado ahí cada fila devuelta por la consulta *(fuera del while)* ... Se podría iterar mediante un [foreach (expresión_array as $valor)](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ....
 }
foreach ($datosMotivos as  $value) {
    print_r($value);/* Obtener el Array completo por cada fila devuelta de la consulta*/
    echo $value['cod'];/* Obtener un campo especifico del array */
 }
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Funciona de maravilla, muchas gracias amigo :)

Answer (score 2):

creo que te refieres a acceder al array rows por fuera del while, si es asi tu problema radica en alcance de las variables

para solucionarlo tendremos que copiarlo en otra variable que se llamara copia

```
$datosMotivos= array();
$copia;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
$copia=$row;
$cod=$row['cod'];
$descripcion=$row['descripcion'];
$motivo=$row['motivo'];
$lugar=$row['lugar'];

$datosMotivos[] = array('cod'=> $cod, 'descripcion'=> $descripcion, 'motivo'=> $motivo, 'lugar'=> $lugar); 
}

//aca puedes trabajar con la variable copia, asi como lo hiciste con $row dentro del ciclo while
$cod=$copia['cod'];
$descripcion=$copia['descripcion'];
$motivo=$copia['motivo'];
$lugar=$copia['lugar'];
```

> para acceder a los elementos dinamicamente:

```
foreach ($copia as  $element) {}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)